# What does this CSS rule mean?

Tags: css, web, client-side

I noticed this CSS rule (see below) applied to the "grid" `div` element.

```
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

What does it exactly mean and why they need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:after` is a *pseudo-element* selector. It defines a pseudo element that will be rendered as the **last child** of the `.grid` element. The `content` property defines the content of this pseudo element.

This particular CSS is so-called **[clear-fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/1069604)**.

They probably have some elements in the `.grid` which are all `float: left`. That causes the `.grid` to *look like* empty. All these elements are no *block* elements so the `.grid` kinda doesn't see them, which makes it width and height equal to zero.

An old popular way to resolve the problem was to add an empty `div` as the last element of the `.grid`

```
<div class="clr"></div>
```

with such style

```
.clr {
    clear: both;
}
```

Nowadays, since we have such beautiful feature as *CSS pseudo-elements* we can spare the DOM and simply add those three lines of CSS you mentioned in the question.

`:after` and `:before` pseudo elements were introduced as the part of the [W3 CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#gen-content). We love them and most of the browsers [support them](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent).

Answer (score 3):

It's a way to clear floats.  It's a better way than adding a `clear` class everywhere that you need it.   This way it will clear the floats of the children (probably columns of a framework that are floated).

The :after will add this element at the end of `grid` (so after all of the children in the HTML).  It's pretty cool!